# Trying to use the super-parameters in old project after upgrading to flutter 3.0.0

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use the new feature of dart (super-parameters) in my project, but every time the build is failed.

this is my code after the migration:

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  int? paramOne;
  String? paramTwo;

  ChildClass({
    this.paramOne,
    this.paramTwo,
    super.paramThree,
    super.paramFour,
  });
// ...
```

this is the error message:

```
[        ] dart_project/lib/src/model/app_model.dart:407:5: Error: The 'super-parameters' language feature is disabled for this library.
[   +1 ms] Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.17 or higher.
[        ]     super.paramThree,
[        ]     ^^^^^
```

pubsec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.17.0 <3.0.0'
```

Comment: Try to do `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`. I faced the same issue and this worked.

Comment: @immadisairaj yes it work, thank you, please answer the question, i will accept it

Comment: Android Studio users: quit & restart IDE after setting `sdk: >=2.17.0 <3.0.0` & running `pub get` may help.  (It did in my case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `flutter clean` to clear the cache and then run `flutter pub get` which will get all the dependencies without cache.